# How to end call via adb in android 2.2.1?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, adb

Im creating small call center like system based on pyadb.

I was developing for my phone which has custom SlimKat ROM - kitkat based.
To call i do :`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:xxxxxxxxx`

To end the call i do `input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL`
and it works like a charm on my phone.

But now my boss want's to use old htc wildfire (buzz) with android 2.2.1
On this phone `adb input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL` gives me '[1] Killed ...`- error. 
I tried to use keycode number instead of KEYCODE_ENDCALL, like this:

`adb shell input keyevent 6`-

this is not giving error but does not have any effect on the phone.

Same for KEYCODE_MUTE.
Curiously KEYCODE_CALL(7) is working as expected.

How can i make it work? Can i change adb commands in anyway? Or maybe installing CyanogenMod(7- I think is the newest for this phone) will help?
Or is this lost fight and i need a newer phone for this?

Answer (score 1):

Found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923550/how-to-make-a-call-via-pc-by-adb-command-on-android/4927028#4927028) and it works for making and ending calls. Still looking for a way to mute Microphone.